# Gradually increasing line Raphael.js

Tags: raphael, line

I was wondering if it would be possible to draw a line in `raphael.js` that will gradually increase its width.

It would start with stroke-width of for example `2px`, and finish with `stroke-width` of `10px`.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's quite straightforward.  Given a Raphael paper element `paper` and path string `pathstr`, just do this:

```
var linepath = paper.path( pathstr ).attr( { stroke: 'black', fill: 'none', 'stroke-width': 2.0 } ).animate( { 'stroke-width': 10.0 }, 5000 );
```

Unless I'm missing something in your request, it really is that easy.